# Identifying child and parent combination groups in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in python containing Child_IDs and their Parent_IDs.

```
df

Child_ID    Parent_ID
0   abc1    abc0
1   ghi7    ghi6
2   ghi1    ghi0
3   ghi0    None
4   ghi10   ghi9
5   abc4    abc3
6   def2    def1
7   abc7    abc6
8   abc6    abc5
9   ghi8    ghi7
10  def4    def3
11  ghi9    ghi8
12  abc2    abc1
13  def0    None
14  ghi6    ghi5
15  abc3    abc2
16  ghi4    ghi3
17  def5    def4
18  abc5    abc4
19  ghi2    ghi1
20  ghi3    ghi2
21  def1    def0
22  abc8    abc7
23  abc0    None
24  def3    def2
25  ghi5    ghi4
```

The logic behind the dataframe IDs is that there are three groups of IDs, i.e., **abc<0 to 8>**,**def<0 to 5>** and **ghi<0 to 10>**.

What I am trying to do is to separate out the three groups **abc**,**def** and **ghi**. Note that the start of a group would be when the Parent_ID has **None** value in it.
The final result would look like this

```
df

Child_ID    Parent_ID
0   abc0    None
1   abc1    abc0
2   abc2    abc1
3   abc3    abc2
4   abc4    abc3
5   abc5    abc4
6   abc6    abc5
7   abc7    abc6
8   abc8    abc7
9   def0    None
10  def1    def0
11  def2    def1
12  def3    def2
13  def4    def3
14  def5    def4
15  ghi0    None
16  ghi1    ghi0
17  ghi2    ghi1
18  ghi3    ghi2
19  ghi4    ghi3
20  ghi5    ghi4
21  ghi6    ghi5
22  ghi7    ghi6
23  ghi8    ghi7
24  ghi9    ghi8
25  ghi10   ghi9
```

Note: This is a sample data I created to simplify a much more complex problem with 800 more columns. The Child_IDs and Parent_IDs are 16 digit random alphanumeric values and the total number of rows are in millions with thousands of 'groups'. So applying a loop, in my opinion, would be too slow in python. I would have loved to give my approach, but I am totally clueless as to how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that sorting directly will not work, since it will be following lexicographic order, which means that `2`>`10`. What we could do is split the numeric part into new columns, concatenate and sort by all columns respectively:

```
df_exp = pd.concat([df[x].str.split('(\d+)', expand=True).add_suffix(x) 
                    for x in df], axis=1)

df_exp_sorted = (df_exp.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
                        .sort_values(by=df_exp.columns.tolist()))

print(df.iloc[df_exp_sorted.index,:].reset_index(drop=True))

   Child_ID Parent_ID
0      abc0      None
1      abc1      abc0
2      abc2      abc1
3      abc3      abc2
4      abc4      abc3
5      abc5      abc4
6      abc6      abc5
7      abc7      abc6
8      abc8      abc7
9      def0      None
10     def1      def0
11     def2      def1
12     def3      def2
13     def4      def3
14     def5      def4
15     ghi0      None
16     ghi1      ghi0
17     ghi2      ghi1
18     ghi3      ghi2
19     ghi4      ghi3
20     ghi5      ghi4
21     ghi6      ghi5
22     ghi7      ghi6
23     ghi8      ghi7
24     ghi9      ghi8
25    ghi10      ghi9
```